"modem hangup," "connect script failed," and "timeout sending config-requests" or a process locking my modem what do I do?
I am working on a project to:

Use the SIM7600X 4G HAT to enable internet access on a Raspberry Pi 4B.
Configure the Raspberry Pi as a Wi-Fi hotspot to then share the 4G internet with other devices.

The Internet connection has been working fine and I was looking into making the Pi an hotspot until recently, I started having issues like "modem hangup," "connect script failed," and "timeout sending config-requests" or a process locking my modem
